# JSON Kafka spout in Apache Storm

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-storm, spout

I am building a Storm topology with Kafka spout. I am consuming from Kafka (without Zookeeper) in a JSON format, and Storm should  output it.
How can I define proper schema for JSON data type?
Currently, I have such code base with basic spout implementation:

```
val cluster = new LocalCluster()
val bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092"
val topologyBuilder = new TopologyBuilder()

val spoutConfig = KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(bootstrapServers, "test").build()

topologyBuilder.setSpout("kafka_spout", new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig), 1)

val config = new Config()
cluster.submitTopology("kafkaTest", config, topologyBuilder.createTopology())

cluster.shutdown()
```

I am new to Apache Storm so would be glad for any advice.

Comment: What do you mean "Kafka (without Zookeeper)"? You still need Zookeeper, and the broker should not act as a producer application, anyway

Comment: Also, is storm a requirement? Kafka Streams should be able to do the same thing

Comment: I have set up Kafka as docker container without Zookeper for local development.
Storm is a requirement

Comment: Kafka requires Zookeeper... If you used the Spotify image, then that one is outdated.. In any case, JSON doesn't have a schema. Storm would just pass it as a string

Comment: Yeah, I used Spotify image but Kafka producer works fine as well as Spark/Flink consumers but not Storm

Comment: I suggest this one for an updated version of Kafka. https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/fast-data-dev/ ; Still, what do you mean by "schema"? Have you seen this? https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.1.0/storm-sql-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a couple of things:

You can define a [`RecordTranslator`](https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.1.0/javadocs/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/RecordTranslator.html). This interface allows you to define how the spout will construct the tuple, based on the `ConsumerRecord` it has read from Kafka.

The default implementation looks like this:

```
public static final Fields FIELDS = new Fields("topic", "partition", "offset", "key", "value");

    @Override
    public List<Object> apply(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record) {
        return new Values(record.topic(),
                record.partition(),
                record.offset(),
                record.key(),
                record.value());
    }

    @Override
    public Fields getFieldsFor(String stream) {
        return FIELDS;
    }
```

As you can see, you will be given a `ConsumerRecord`, which is a type built into the underlying Kafka client library, and then have to turn it into a `List<Object>` which will be the tuple values. If you wanted to do something complex with the record before emitting the data, this would be how you would do it. For example, if you wanted to stuff the key, value and offset into a data structure that it then emitted, you could do that here. You use the translator like `KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(bootstrapServers, "test").setRecordTranslator(myTranslator).build()`

A better alternative if you only want to deserialize the key/value into one of your own data classes, is to implement a [`Deserializer`](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.html). This will let you define how to deserialize the key/value you get from Kafka. If you want to deserialize e.g. the value to your own data class, you can do it using this interface.

The default `StringDeserializer` does this:

```
    @Override
    public String deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        try {
            if (data == null)
                return null;
            else
                return new String(data, encoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error when deserializing byte[] to string due to unsupported encoding " + encoding);
        }
    }
```

Once you've created your own `Deserializer`, you use it by doing something like `KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(bootstrapServers, "test").setProp(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, YourDeserializer.class).build()`. There's a similar consumer property for setting the value deserializer.